# How to install Force.com IDE for Eclipse

Tags: lightning, force.com, aura, ide

Salesforce retired Force.com IDE for Ecplise. Is there any way to install it? Or is it possible to work on Lightning Aura Component in Sandbox from Visual Code?

Comment: Yes you can work with Visual Studio Code and sandboxes. Here's a helpful link: https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/development-models

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this topic is very well documented by Salesforce and future of IDEs.

Comment: @Shohrat, as you know salesforce has retired force.com IDE for eclipse, why do you still want to know ways to install it. You can work with visual studio code to develop not only  aura components but lots of other components.